# Can't detect collision properly using Rectangle.Intersects()

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I'm using a single sprite sheet image as the main texture for my breakout game. The image is this:

[image: breakout_sprite_sheet]

My code is a little confusing, since I'm creating two elements from the same Texture using a `Point`, to represent the element size and its position on the sheet, a `Vector`, to represent its position on the viewport and a `Rectangle` that represents the element itself.

```
Texture2D sheet;

Point paddleSize = new Point(112, 24);
Point paddleSheetPosition = new Point(0, 240);
Vector2 paddleViewportPosition;
Rectangle paddleRectangle;

Point ballSize = new Point(24, 24);
Point ballSheetPosition = new Point(160, 240);
Vector2 ballViewportPosition;
Rectangle ballRectangle;
Vector2 ballVelocity;
```

My initialization is a little confusing as well, but it works as expected:

```
paddleViewportPosition = new Vector2((GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Width - paddleSize.X) / 2, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Height - (paddleSize.Y * 2));
paddleRectangle = new Rectangle(paddleSheetPosition.X, paddleSheetPosition.Y, paddleSize.X, paddleSize.Y);

Random random = new Random();
ballViewportPosition = new Vector2(random.Next(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Width), random.Next(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Top, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Height / 2));
ballRectangle = new Rectangle(ballSheetPosition.X, ballSheetPosition.Y, ballSize.X, ballSize.Y);
ballVelocity = new Vector2(3f, 3f);
```

And the drawing:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(sheet, paddleViewportPosition, paddleRectangle, Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(sheet, ballViewportPosition, ballRectangle, Color.White);
```

The problem is I can't detect the collision properly, using this code:

```
if(ballRectangle.Intersects(paddleRectangle))
{
    ballVelocity.Y = -ballVelocity.Y;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're testing collision based on [`sourceRectangles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433990.aspx) for the sprite sheet texture. Those rectangles (`paddleRectangle`, `ballRectangle`) are defined in terms of *texture coordinates* - that is where those sprites are on the sheet. It makes no sense to test those rectangles for collision.

You need to **use screen coordinates for collision**, that is, you need different rectangles defined with *screen positions*:

```
Rectangle paddleViewportRectangle = new Rectangle(paddleViewportPosition.X, 
                                              paddleViewportPosition.Y, 
                                              paddleSize.X, 
                                              paddleSize.Y);

Rectangle ballViewportRectangle = new Rectangle(ballViewportPosition.X,
                                                ballViewportPosition.Y,
                                                ballSize.X,
                                                ballSize.Y);

if(ballViewportRectangle.Intersects(paddleViewportRectangle))
{
    ballVelocity.Y = -ballVelocity.Y;
}
```

Comment: I do have two different rectangles (see the edited post). I'm quite sure there is something wront on the initialization though...

Comment: @DanielRibeiro I've made an edit to make it clear. Try using this entire code block for your collision. Your initialization is OK.

Comment: I got the sourceRectangles matter. Is there any easier way to achieve that sprite sheet issue without having to create two rectangles for each object?

Comment: @DanielRibero I don't think so, in fact I believe that how you're doing it is the correct (intended) way to do it. The code in your question (except for the collision bit) is OK. Or are you talking about these two additional rectangles in my answer?

Comment: Nah, I'm just a freak when it comes to best practices and repeated code. I'll get into it now, since your solution worked perfectly. Many thanks! I'm so happy the documentation clarifies so much just on a simple method signature!